# Why is the nominal determination indefinite in the phrase "a miniature Great Wall"?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article

As is in the title, why is the nominal determination indefinite in the following noun phrase?

> a miniature Great Wall

I wondered if it was because this is a wall, and *miniature* and *great* are adjectives, and because its syntactic function is an object complement? I'm not sure; I am really confused about the grammar here.

Thank you!

Comment: Grammatically, I have no clue… but strip it right down to "It's a wall" It's not any specific wall - even as miniature replicas go, it's unlikely to be the only one, it's not **the** Great Wall of China, which at the last census still achieved a count of 1. If the phrase were in response to the question, "Which wall do you mean, this one or that one?" you might need 'the miniature Great Wall' to differentiate from the model of Jericho next to it.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of *a* rather than *the* implies that there are multiple miniature replicas of *the* Great Wall of China. This is just one of many, as opposed to the Wall itself, which is unique.

Grammar doesn't dictate the usage here, as both *a* and *the* serve the same grammatical function. It's purely a semantic distinction.

Comment: Actually, you could use *a* here even if there was only one miniature in existence.